# CSS media print anchor link to be clickable if printed as PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pdf

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google anchor link</a>
```

it appears on website as:
[Google anchor link](https://www.google.com)

At print it display as:

Google anchor link(https://www.google.com)

to solve this I've add in CSS:

```
@media print {
    a:link:after,
    a:visited:after {
        content: "" !important;
}}
```

Now at print appear as:
[Google anchor link](https://www.google.com) (so link isn't now afther the anchor).

**The problem:**

If I choose instead of normal printer a virtual printer(like [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com)) to print the page in a .PDF file **the anchor link stopped** to be clickable in my .PDF created file, it is displayed as text only: Google anchor link.

Anchor text clickable in a .PDF file should be possible as long as I see a lot of .PDF files that have "anchor links clickable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Maybe help others too!

Virtual printers like [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com) does not print hyperlinks, other virtual printers(premium) allow you to print hyperlinks.

**Best solution** to print as PDF directly from webpages is Google Chrome(I didn't know that Google Chrome has implemented this features in his core - no need for any extension).

Print, **Ctrl+P** in Google Chrome, change destination and choose **=>** **Save as PDF**(and all hyperlinks will be clickable in your created PDF document).

You can save web pages as PDF files directly in Google Chrome **without** installying an PDF drivers or any extensions.

See attached picture!

[image: Save as PDF directly from Google Chrome!]

Comment: "and all hyperlinks will be clickable" unless they aren't.  which is happening to me right now.